# If we increase the radius of a circle, does the arc's length equal the length of two end points of the arc?

Tags: geometry

[image]

I'm taking an online course and in it, the professor says that if we increase the radius of a circle, the arc's length will be equal to the length of line joining the end points of the arc (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=46Za6X9LFI0).

However, when I actually drew the circles, I get something different (they aren't exactly getting equal):

How come? What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Wait, I think I got it. The point isn't just to make the circle larger, but to increase $r$ and decrease $l$. And if we decrease $l$, automatically, $l$ and $s$ will be equal. Correct?

[image: Image!]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The context here is that the length $l$ is kept the *same size* as the circle grows. So the *angle* becomes smaller, and thus the difference between the arc and the line segment decreases. Note where they say $r \gg l$. That means that $l$ is *really* small compared to $r$ in the cases we're interested in. So the true picture is actually something like this:

[image]

The image is too crude to see the difference between the arc and the segment in the large circle, which supports the claim that the difference becoms negligible.